# Java Compilation error "method setSchema in class MpsPojo cannot be applied to given types;"

Tags: java

Hi I saw some of the related question related to this but didn't find any to the point solution.

I have a POJO class defined as:

> > MpsPojo.java

```
    public class MpsPojo {

   private String mfr;
   private String prod;
   private String sche;


   public String getMfr() {
      return mfr;
   }

   public void setMfr(String mfr) {
      this.mfr = mfr;
   }

   public String getProd() {
        return prod;
   }

   public void setProd()  {
        this.prod = prod;
   }

   public String getSchema()   {
        return sche;
   }

   public void setSchema()   {
        this.sche = sche;
   }
}
```

I have 2nd business Logic as:: MpsLogic.java

```
    public class  MpsLogic {

public void calculateAssert(MpsPojo mpspojo){

        String manufacturer;
        String product;
        String schema;

        manufacturer = mpspojo.getMfr();
        product = mpspojo.getProd();
        schema = mpspojo.getSchema();

        String url = "http://localhost:9120/dashboards/all/list/"+manufacturer+"/"+product+"/"+schema;
    }
    }
```

And final class, the Test class is :: FinalLogic.java

```
public class FinalLogic {

    MpsPojo mpspojon = new MpsPojo();
    MpsLogic mpslogicn = new MpsLogic();
    @Test
    public void firstTest() {

                    mpspojon.setMfr("m1");
                    mpspojon.setProd("p1");
                    mpspojon.setSchema("sch1");
                    mpslogicn.calculateAssert(mpspojon);
                    System.out.println("Printing from Final class");
                    }
```

}

In program FinalLogic.java, this gives me the Compilation error error `method setSchema in class MpsPojo cannot be applied to given types;`

But when I comment the lines `mpspojon.setProd("p1");` and `mpspojon.setSchema("sch1");` then this works fine without error.

I debugged a lot but dint find any clue for this. Any help will be very helpful for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `String` arguments to `setProd` and `setSchema` as you have already done with `setMfr`:

```
public void setProd(String prod)  {
                      ^     ^
```

and

```
public void setSchema(String sche) { 
                       ^      ^
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I was using some ones others Pojo class.. so dint noticed.

Answer (score 3):

`setSchema()` receives no parameters in your declaration. Change it to:

```
public void setSchema(String sche) {
    this.sche = sche;
}
```

Same holds true for `setProd`

If you use any IDE, I advise you:

1. look into the warnings that you will get (the assignment `this.sche = sche` will give warning `The assignment to variable thing has no effect` in case of no argument method).
2. Generate the setters/getters automatically, don't code them by yourself (thus avoiding any possible typing mistakes). E.g. in Eclipse that will be `alt`+`shift`+`s`, then `r`

Comment: Thanks a lot.. this solved the problem.. Unfortunately I am using vim editor, so dint noticed . Thanks again.

Comment: @JK_Jha However, you still are compiling in somehow. Eclipse is just visualizing standard jdk warning in this case I think.